# Issues invoking calls in Windows Azure Management Libraries 1.0.1

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sdk, visual-studio-2013

When I invoke any async method in the azure management library the application crashes without any exception or other indication. I am using visual studio 2013 .net 4.5 and [Windows Azure Management Libraries 1.0.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net#windows-azure-management-libraries)

```
private static async void ListLocation()
{
     const string filePathCert = @"C:\path\to\certificate";
     var certificate = new X509Certificate2(filePathCert, "password");

     var credentials = new CertificateCloudCredentials("xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx", certificate);
     try
     {
         using (ManagementClient client = CloudContext.Clients.CreateManagementClient(credentials))
         {
             var result = await client.Locations.ListAsync(); //Here the application terminates without any message /exception
             var locations = result.Locations;
             foreach (var location in locations)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Location: {0}", location.Name);

                 foreach (var feature in location.AvailableServices)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(feature);
                 }
             }
        }
    }
    catch(Excepiton ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `async void`; it has very awkward error handling semantics. I explain this in more detail in my MSDN article on [best practices for asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Instead, use `async Task`, and ensure that the calling code `await`s the returned task. This will ensure that your code will observe any exceptions.